# How to create a new column with repeated values based on another column?

Tags: r

Here is what I currently Have. I have a column named "test1M", which has values of either 0 or 1. If the value is 1, I want to set the next 20 values in column "test1Mxx" to value 1.

If I run this code, I get an error of (Error in if (data$test1M[x] == 1) { : argument is of length zero).

Whats a better way for me to do this? The code is pretty repetitive, so I would like to minimize that if possible. If there is a way to turn this into a function that would be preferable, so I could change the number of values (for instance, maybe the following 25 values, or 40 values, etc.)

```
for(x in data$test1){
  if(data$test1[x]==1){
    data$test2[x+1]=1
    data$test2[x+2]=1
    data$test2[x+3]=1
    data$test2[x+4]=1
    data$test2[x+5]=1
    data$test2[x+6]=1
    data$test2[x+7]=1
    data$test2[x+8]=1
    data$test2[x+9]=1
    data$test2[x+10]=1
    data$test2[x+11]=1
    data$test2[x+12]=1
    data$test2[x+13]=1
    data$test2[x+14]=1
    data$test2[x+15]=1
    data$test2[x+16]=1
    data$test2[x+17]=1
    data$test2[x+18]=1
    data$test2[x+19]=1
    data$test2[x+20]=1}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop doesn't work because `x` is a value of `data$test1`, not an index of it. You need something like:

```
data$test2 <- data$test1
for (x in seq_along(data$test1))
  if (data$test1[x] == 1) data$test2[x + 1:20] <- 1
```